# Generar variables dinamicamente para llenar un list

Tags: php, lista

Buenas tengo la siguiente duda, tengo este código en el que lleno las variables de un list dependiendo los valores de una variable string a la que le separo los items segun los ; que traiga dicho string, sialgun valor del string cambia me los muestra ok.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora como puedo hacer para generar dinamicamente el numero de variables que contiene el list, porque en el ejemplo tengo 4 variables por que el string dato tiene 4 datos, pero en el caso que el string dato contenga "1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8" necesitaria que adentro del list haya 8 variables no 4.
Probe de la siguiente forma y obviamente esta mal porque el array se llena con ,,,,, porque las variables generadas en ${"Numero" . $i} no tienen valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego probe de esta forma (ya se q estaba mal era para ver que salia) y luego al pasar al array a string y separarlo por comas guarde los datos en $separado_por_comas, la cuestion es que si hago un echo de $separado_por_comas me muestra lo datos ok pero si meto esa variable en el list no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por otro lado si copio el echo y lo meto en la variable si funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En fin saliendo de todos estos print y explicaciones (que tal vez no tengan sentido y arme cualquier cosa) como puedo hacer para crear variables dinamicamente para completar un list dependiendo de los datos que contenga otra variable (string del cual obtengo los datos separandolo por ;)

Comment: Ciertamente, muchas explicaciones... sin decir para qué exactamente quieres las variables... Si es para imprimirlas directamente no veo por qué tengas que usar `list`. ¿? Puedes crear un array directamente usando `explode` sobre los valores separados por `;`  y leer dinámicamente cada valor en un bucle `for`. ¿Te interesa eso o tienes que usar `list()` obligatoriamente? Ejemplo: **`$datos="1; 2; 3; 4";
$arrDatos=explode(";",$datos);
foreach ($arrDatos as $dato){
    echo $dato;
}`** Resultado: **`1 2 3 4`**

Comment: Gracias por comentar, necesito si o si list, ahi puse parte del codigo que me acordaba no tengo todo a mano ahora, pero eso es lo que necesito , generar variables en el list(), necesito que cada dato del string separado por el ; se convierta en una variable al final, en el que me pasas ahi $dato equivale a 1,2,3,4 necesitaria que quede $dato1 = 1, $dato2 = 2, $dato3= 3, $dato4 = 4